# shape matrix help(keeps crashing)

Tags: c

I am trying to print a matrix of shapes, but my program continues to crash. what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int row, col;

    printf("How many rows?\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("How many columns?\n");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    int i=0,j=0;

    while (i<row)
    {
        i ++;

        while(j < col)

        {
            printf("$");
            j ++;
        }
        return(0);
    }
}
```

I have tried trouble shooting by initializing the counters, and trying to find syntax error. Also how can i become better at trouble shooting? I am an entry level C Programmer.

Comment: You are increasing the variables that you are comparing to. So how will the conditions end the loops? There is no syntax error, just a conceptual one.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. Also, get a piece of paper and a pencil. Mentally step through each line of code one at a time and write down the values of each variable.

Comment: I don't see the point of `return(0);` Would `printf("\n");` be better, once the loops are fixed?

Comment: Did you mis-post the code, or did you change it in reponse to comments? If the latter, please don't do that, because the question asked is now pointless, apart from needing to reset `j` to the original value at the start of the inner loop.

Comment: It should be `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

## include

```
int main ()
{
    int row, col;

    printf("How many rows?\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("How many columns?\n");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    int i=0,j=0;

    while (i<row)
    {
        i++;

        j = 0;
        while(j < col)
        {
            printf("$");
            j++;
        }
//         return(0); you don't need a return here
    }
}
```

or, use for loop will be better

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        printf("$");
}
```

Also, validate the row and col before use them will be a good idea

```
if (row < 0 || row > YourRowCount || col < 0 || col > YourColCount)
{
    printf("Error row / col: %d,%d\n", row, col);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from loop it it's first cycle with `return(0)`!

Also if you are allowed to use `for` loop you can simply do it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int row, col;

    printf("How many rows?\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("How many columns?\n");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("$");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're Initializing twice the loop iterators. Consider using `for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)`

Comment: as for your second comment you're right about the 1 maximum iteration, but for your first comment you can't really pass void as a parameter to main(). Thanks

Comment: The `void` means that **no** parameters are accepted. A function should be well-defined.

Comment: Edited again, have a look please!